# Grails 2.4.4 UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES cglib 2.2.2

Tags: grails, dependencies, cglib

I am trying to upgrade a project to grails version 2.4.4 but it keep failing with the following error message:

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: cglib#cglib;2.2.2: configuration not found in cglib#cglib;2.2.2: 'compile'. It was required from org.grails#grails-plugin-testing;2.4.4 runtime
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- cglib:cglib:2.2.2
(Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more  information):
- cglib:cglib:2.2.2
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

This s kind of weird since the library is available. I can see it under grails-2.4.4\lib\cglib\cglib\jars and in my home directory under .grails\ivy-cache\cglib\cglib\jars

My GRAILS_HOME is set correctly and for what I can see all looks fine but when I do a refresh dependencies it keeps throwing this error.

Comment: maybe in BuildConfig changing grails.project.dependency.resolver from maven to ivy would help?

Comment: @cyan You really shouldn't do that.

Comment: Does it happen with a newly created 2.4.4 app?  One thing to look for is confirm that you have the necessary repository configured in `BuildConfig.groovy`.  For example, does the problem happen if you have `mavenCentral()` configured?

Comment: I ran into a similar dependency problem in Grails.  I was able to solve the issue with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28836825/311525)

Answer (score 18):

In upgrading from Grails 2.1 to 2.4.4 I found I had that same issue.  The resolution was to explicitly set:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
```

in BuildConfig.groovy. Then I was able to move on to the next issue in the upgrade ... ;-)