# Grails plugins do not resolve with Bamboo

Tags: grails, bamboo

We're using Bamboo for build management and have a Grails task configured to handle the builds, but whenever I run it I get a bunch of Unresolved dependencies on all of the plugins:

```
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#rest-client-builder;2.0.1: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#rest;0.8: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#quartz;1.0.1: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#ckeditor;3.6.6.1.1: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#cache;1.0.1: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#quartz-monitor;0.3-RC3: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#scaffolding;2.0.1: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#spring-events;1.2: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.8.3: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0.1: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#aws-sdk;1.6.4: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#redis;1.5.5: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#hibernate;3.6.10.10: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            :: org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.8.24: not found
build   05-Mar-2015 20:58:21            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Based on the output it looks like it's trying the correct urls to download the plugins, but it's not working for some reason. I haven't used Bamboo before and this project was already set up in there, so is there something obvious that I'm just missing here?

Comment: try `refresh-dependencies`

Comment: This might help: [Grails unable to install plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin).

Comment: I tried refresh-dependencies but it results in the same output. It works if I run the same build locally with the same code, so there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the BuildConfig. it's just that when it's on Bamboo, the plugins do not resolve.

Comment: I ran into the same issue.  It was resolved by adding a new maven repo.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28836825/311525